# Natural coordinates on tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

In Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, he says that

> ...the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold has a natural structure as a smooth manifold in its own right. The natural coordinates we constructed on $TM$ make it look, locally, like the Cartesian product of an open subset of $M$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$.

He defines the natural coordinates on $TM$ to be $(x^i, v^i)$ given by $\tilde{\varphi}: \pi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, where
$$\tilde{\varphi}\Big(v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\Big) = (x^1(p), \ldots, x^n(p), v^1, \ldots, v^n), \quad p \in M $$
and $\pi: TM \rightarrow M$ is the natural projection map $\pi(p, v) = p$.

To me, it seems that we use $\tilde{\varphi}$ to make $TM$ locally look like an open subset of the cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself, so $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. How does this imply that $TM$ locally looks like an open subset of $M \times \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$TM$ is dimension $2n$, so locally it looks like $U\times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ (not $U\times \mathbb{R}$), where $U\subset M$ can be identified with an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. On this open subset, the first $n$ coordinates are position coordinates $x^1,...,x^n$, while the second $n$ coordinates are velocity coordinates $\partial_1,...,\partial_n$.

Comment: So we are using the fact that $(x^1, \ldots, x^n)$ is a homeomorphism $M \supset U \rightarrow V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$? I am new to bundles and manifolds, so I have not yet seen the interpretation where the  second set of $n$ coordinates represent a velocity.

Comment: The velocity interpretation comes from understanding $T_pM$ as the set of velocity vectors though $M$ (equivalence classes of curves), then localizing this idea to all points $p\in U$. Lee's chapter 3 talks on this in detail.

Comment: I read that chapter, and what I got from the section on velocity vectors of curves is that if we have a curve $\gamma$, then the velocity of $\gamma$ at $t_0$, $\gamma'(t_0)$, is an element of $T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$. I never thought to make a connection with this object to the tangent bundle, as $\gamma$ has dimension one whereas in the tangent bundle we have dimension $n$ in $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$. Similarly, since the velocity vector has dimension 1, how do we view $T_pM$ as the set of velocity vectors through $M$, shouldn't they all need dimension $n$? Am I missing something?

Comment: @CBBAM The velocity vector $\gamma'(t)$ for a smooth curve $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to M$ lives in $T_{\gamma(t)}M$, which is an $n$-dimensional space. I think you might be confusing this with the fact that the *domain* of $\gamma$ is $1$-dimensional (and that the image of $\gamma$ in $M$ is an immersed submanifold of dimension $1$, as long as $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$).

Comment: @TobErnack Yes that was the mistake I was making, thank you!